# WooCommerce plugin for easy checkout for schools

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Does anyone know of a plugin that will allow you to list all of your products on a single page and then the user simply needs to select the product in a checkbox to add it to the cart before proceeding to checkout?

I would like to use it for school stationary where the user can add multiple products as most grades are given a list to buy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://codecanyon.net/item/add-multiple-products-to-cart-at-once-in-woocommerce/11853060) plugin for adding multiple Products to Cart at once in Woocommerce for your purpose.

Hope this plugin is useful for you.